# Array like argument in function documentation

Tags: methods, parameters, arguments, documentation

Sorry if my question is stupid, all of us have seen many function arguments for methods documented as this

`redis.createClient(port[, host][, options])`

I'm unable to understand how it works the `port` and why `host` argument is in array and it starts with `,`. The snippet above is from

https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an array. Square brackets are typically used in this manner to indicate optional parameters.

Basically it means that you can use it as any one of the following:

- `redis.createClient(port)`
- `redis.createClient(port, host)`
- `redis.createClient(port, options)`
- `redis.createClient(port, host, options)`

Sometimes the notation `redis.createClient(port[, host[, options]])` is used instead, which implies it is not possible to use it as `redis.createClient(port, options)`.

Similar notation is also used when documenting commands. (e.g., from `ls` manual: `ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...`)